Does freelancing experience count as official work experience?
I'm a Software Developer and worked for an MNC in India for 1.5 years (2014-2015), as a front-end developer after which I quit the job to pursue freelancing full-time. After working as a freelancer for about 9 years now, I would like to start applying for full-time roles, mostly for software work based on front-end technologies like React/Next.js/Angular.
My question is: Would recruiters see my freelance experience as "industry" work experience? And would I be eligible to apply on jobs that ask for say 3+ or 5+ Years of experience?

Assuming you worked with IT, why would your freelance experience not be considered work experience?

@morsor I was asking more in the sense that would it be considered similar to someone who has worked with a company for the same amount of time. Or is freelance experience given a backseat compared to a person who's worked in organizations..

While it does count as "work experience", the real problem comes from having been a freelancer. Nine years as a freelancer gives you experiences and ways of thinking that are not the best for an "employee." You may have learned how to fire clients. You may have learned how to push back on "crazy" client ideas. Employees are expected to put up with such once the manager has signed off on this client.
When I was an employee, the company once hired someone who was trying to come back after being a freelancer for a while. The attitude differences between that person and the rest of the employees was very noticeable. It was not a good fit for both the company and that person. After as many years as I have as a freelancer, I would not fit into the corporate environment either.

I see.. well I am a bit aware, that the kind of thinking and working with an organization would differ (having worked previously with one) It's more a question of being considered eligible for the roles that require same experience as someone who's worked with companies

Of course, these days many companies seem to have a great deal of interest in fostering a workforce with diverse experience and ideas. And different companies themselves have a wide variety of environments and company culture.  Having become accustomed to freelancing might make it harder to find a good fit in the corporate world, but that shouldn't be assumed to ruin you forever for working for someone else.

OP asks about recruiters. Many recruiters see freelancing as being a big red flag for employee positions. To move from freelancing to employee would be done best by networking with the business owners directly instead of looking to recruiters for positions.

Absolutely!! The recruiter may or may not hold it in the same regard as more traditional experience but it is relevant experience regardless. I would not let this deter you from applying to a job. Do not try to mask the experience as something other than free lancing though.

Do not try to mask the experience as something other than free lancing though. Like what?
